# Maximum length of high-speed LVDS cable in automotive environment versus using SerDes

Tags: cables, transmission-line, lvds

I would like to connect a small TFT display that uses LVDS, 4 channels for data and 1 channel for clock. Data rate is maximum 200 Mbps per lane. Very strict EMC requirements are applicable, namely automotive.

What would be the maximum length of a typical LVDS cable that would still work in this environment? Length could be up to 1 meter. I would use twisted pairs in any case. Shielding would preferably be avoided but could be applied if needed. Common mode chokes can be implemented on the PCB; clamps on the cable should be avoided if possible.

I am wondering from what length onwards I should use something like an FPD Link III SerDes (e.g. TI DS90UB927)? Or would that be overkill? BOM cost is important.

Theory like [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snla187/snla187.pdf) suggests that I am still well within the regime for LVDS, but it does not quantify the EMC aspects, which are crucial in this application.

Comment: Could you use twisted pairs? Common-mode chokes?

Comment: @CL. I would use twisted pairs in any case; common-mode chokes could be added to the board (preferably not on the cable). Updated my question to reflect this. Do you think that with twisted pairs it could work at a length of 1 meter?

Comment: The additional cables cost more, and are harder to install. But I don't see much of a reason that the single SerDes output should be much less sensitive than the original LVDSes. Ultimately, you would have to measure yourself.

Comment: @Martin - 200 Mbps at 1 meter for LVDS should not be a problem.  You should use twisted shielded pairs so as to provide the minimum loop area for any common mode currents that may flow.  Make sure the shields are properly terminated at both ends of the cable.  Improper shield connections (such as pig tails) are frequently a cause of failing EMI/EMC certifications.

Answer (score 1):

The standard deciding factor of whether a given transmission distance is practical, is how much jitter is observed by receiving nodes. This is application dependent; some applications require 5% or less jitter, whereas others tolerate up to 20%: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an-1177.pdf

There are a number of studies that look at how the signal integrity is affected by the transmission rate and cable length. However, normally you did not spec the maximum cable length for your application:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snla187/snla187.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla127/slla127.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt163/slyt163.pdf

Comment: OP did say that the maximum cable length was 1 meter.

Answer (score 1):

FOR EMC, you can check this application note :
[an4511-common-mode-filters-stmicroelectronics](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4511-common-mode-filters-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

There is an automotive range of CMF :
[STMicroelectronics Automotive EMI filters](https://www.st.com/en/protections-and-emi-filters/automotive-emi-filters-ecmf-and-asip.html#products)

I guess it is mandatory if you use unshielded twisted pairs for weight concern.

Answer (score 0):

Routing differential pairs any distance through air, is dangerous due to the input common mode range of the receivers.  Typically LVDS is received by no more than 3.3V supplies, giving about a 1.65V working range.  A hand-held radio or cellphone keys up and you can easily get several volts in the environment, and down goes your lane (corrupted).  Let alone transients from motors, relays, etc.

Given this is a display, perhaps the transients would be acceptable (momentary graphical glitches, or at worst, frame drops), though I would still worry about the ESD ratings of receivers or transmitters involved in this path.

Fortunately, a perfect model exists: HDMI uses LVDS(like) signals, inside a *shielded cable*.  This is tolerant of ambient fields and robust against transients.

Whether a finer compromise is possible, such as trading shielding for CMCs, would likely require a trip to the test lab.  At the very least, much more information would have to be provided (what transmitters, receivers; environment and grounding of both boards, the cable route, any nearby noise sources, proximity to passenger or environmental sources, etc. etc.) to have any kind of discussion about it.